# Failed password attempt - How do i code that in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, authentication, passwords

Question is not correctly framed i know, how do i code the below logic in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005) to increase a failure count for user registration system.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (FailedPasswordWindowStart < GETDATE() >= 
dateadd(minute,20,FailedPasswordWindowStart)) THEN 'Increase' ELSE 'Same' END FROM users
```

simply put, when the current time is within last attempt and time windows from last attempt then increase the failure count.

Comment: You are missing an `END` before your `FROM users` if that is your question

Comment: @juergend sorry, i solved my own question. thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more easier way i could have done this. replace the variables as parameters to the stored procedure you might have created.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ABS((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@LastAttempt,GETDATE())) <= @TimeWindow
THEN 'Increase' 
ELSE 'Same' END
```

`@Window` - Time window within which the if a attempt is made should increase the count

`@LastAttempt` - Last failure attempt(date and time)

#### Edit

added `ABS` since the value obtained could be negative too :)